# How do I get my Lua code to read CSV files?

Tags: csv, lua, mediawiki

I have the following example CSV file. The actual data is different, but I want to use this as an example.

```
username,firstname,lastname,age,nationality

first_user,Mark,Smith,19,Canada
dogs_are_better_than_cats,Linda,Robertson,47,Sweden
lamborghini33,Chad,Carson,33,Finland
doctorpepper,Rachel,Hill,41,United States
shin0bi,John,Prescott,15,United States
bigshot1997,Spamton,Spamton,31,Cyber City
```

What I want is to be able to write a LUA module (MediaWiki specifically) that reads this CSV. More specifically, I want to be able to have something that takes a username as an argument and returns some other information, such as full name and age. How do I do that? Thank you. Notably, I can guarantee that no two users have the same username, so I should be able to get the one and only full name and age associated with whichever username is used as an argument. Thank you.

Comment: Search `string.split(",")` and `io.open(filepath, "rb").

Comment: @rpatters1 Lua has no `string.split` by default.

Answer (score 0):

`Module:CSV`:

```lua
local split = mw.text.split -- localise the function provided by Scribunto.

local csv = [[
username,firstname,lastname,age,nationality

first_user,Mark,Smith,19,Canada
dogs_are_better_than_cats,Linda,Robertson,47,Sweden
lamborghini33,Chad,Carson,33,Finland
doctorpepper,Rachel,Hill,41,United States
shin0bi,John,Prescott,15,United States
bigshot1997,Spamton,Spamton,31,Cyber City
]]

local lines = split( csv, '\n', true ) -- split the CSV by newline as plain text.

local users = {} -- Associative table of users.
for i, line in ipairs( lines ) do -- iterate over table lines with numeric keys.
    if i > 1 and line ~= '' then -- omit the header and any empty line.
        -- Split the line by comma as plain text and unpack the returned table.
        local username, firstname, lastname, age, nationality = unpack( split( line, ',', true ) )
        users [username] = {
            firstname   = firstname,
            lastname    = lastname,
            age         = tonumber( age ), -- convert to number.
            nationality = nationality
        }
    end
end

-- This table will be returned by the module:
return {
    -- Example: {{#invoke:CSV|user|dogs_are_better_than_cats|lastname}}.
    user = function( frame )
         -- frame.args [1] and frame.args [2] contain the first and the second
         -- unnamed arguments to {{#invoke:CSV|user|nick|field}}, respectively.
        return users [frame.args [1]] [frame.args [2]]
    end
}
```

`{{#invoke:CSV|user|dogs_are_better_than_cats|lastname}}` will give `Robertson`.

Below is a more sophisticated variant that makes no assumptions about the data structure, except counting on the user's ID being in the first column, and gets the necessary columns from the header line of the CSV string.

```lua
local split = mw.text.split -- localise the function provided by Scribunto.

local csv = [[
username,firstname,lastname,age,nationality

first_user,Mark,Smith,19,Canada
dogs_are_better_than_cats,Linda,Robertson,47,Sweden
lamborghini33,Chad,Carson,33,Finland
doctorpepper,Rachel,Hill,41,United States
shin0bi,John,Prescott,15,United States
bigshot1997,Spamton,Spamton,31,Cyber City
]]

local lines = split( csv, '\n', true ) -- split the CSV by newline as plain text.

local users, columns = {}, nil -- Associative tables for users and data columns.
for i, line in ipairs( lines ) do -- iterate over table lines with numeric keys.
    if line ~= '' then -- omit any empty line.
        -- Split the line by comma as plain text.
        local chunks = split( line, ',', true )
        if not columns then
            -- This is the header line.
            columns = mw.clone( chunks ) -- deep copy.
        else
            -- This is one of the lines with user's data.
            -- We assume that the first column should be used as the key.
            local id, fields = chunks [1], {}
            for col, value in ipairs( chunks ) do
                -- Convert to number, if possible, or leave as is.
                fields [columns [col]] = tonumber( value ) or value
            end
            users [id] = fields
        end
    end
end

-- This table will be returned by the module:
return {
    -- Example: {{#invoke:CSV|user|dogs_are_better_than_cats|lastname}}.
    user = function( frame )
         -- frame.args [1] and frame.args [2] contain the first and the second
         -- unnamed arguments to {{#invoke:CSV|user|nick|field}}, respectively.
        return users [frame.args [1]] [frame.args [2]]
    end
}
```

And another variant, where each column name found in the comma-separated text is exported as a separate function:

```lua
local split = mw.text.split -- localise a function provided by Scribunto.

local csv = [[
username,firstname,lastname,age,nationality

first_user,Mark,Smith,19,Canada
dogs_are_better_than_cats,Linda,Robertson,47,Sweden
lamborghini33,Chad,Carson,33,Finland
doctorpepper,Rachel,Hill,41,United States
shin0bi,John,Prescott,15,United States
bigshot1997,Spamton,Spamton,31,Cyber City
]]

local lines = split( csv, '\n', true ) -- split the CSV by newline as plain text.

local users, columns = {}, nil -- Associative tables for users and data columns.
for i, line in ipairs( lines ) do -- iterate over table lines with numeric keys.
    if line ~= '' then -- omit any empty line.
        -- Split the line by comma surrounded by optional spaces.
        local chunks = split( line, '%s*,%s*', false )
        if not columns then
            -- This is the header line.
            columns = mw.clone( chunks ) -- deep copy.
        else
            -- This is one of the lines with user's data.
            -- We assume that the first column should be used as the key.
            local id, fields = chunks [1], {}
            for col, value in ipairs( chunks ) do
                -- Convert to number, if possible, or leave as is.
                fields [columns [col]] = tonumber( value ) or value
            end
            users [id] = fields
        end
    end
end

-- This table will be returned by the module.
local p = {}
-- Export each data column as a separate function.
for _, column in ipairs( columns ) do
    p [column] = function( frame )
        -- frame.args [1] contains the first unnamed argument to {{#invoke:CSV|field|nick}}.
        return users [frame.args [1]] [column]
    end
end

-- Example: {{#invoke:CSV|lastname|dogs_are_better_than_cats}}.
return p
```

`{{#invoke:CSV|lastname|dogs_are_better_than_cats}}` will return `Robertson`.